# Can we change msconfig - Load Basic Driver Settings to Load All by editing system file?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, troubleshooting, msconfig

I've HP g6-1209AX. My keyboard & track pad stopped working abruptly. I restarted the computer couple of times but nothing happened. I was able to login using my pin by using On-screen keyboard. So, further, I decided to go to *msconfig* and try booting with just basic drivers (load basic drivers).

After that, neither I/O devices are working nor I'm able to login. When I enter my pin, it reloads the login screen and asks me to re-enter the pin. It threw Loginui.exe error couple of times (not any more).

As an ultimate solution, I decided to format my systems so I booted it from USB with Windows 8.1 however, when it asks me *Press any key to boot from USB* it doesn't accept inputs from my external - usb keyboard. I don't have any legacy options to enable in my boot by the way.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me out. One solution I see is reverting *msconfig* settings from a system file by attaching this hard drive to other system.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that the problem is present at the beginning of the boot process, it is either caused by a hardware issue or BIOS misconfiguration.

You should try connecting an external keyboard to go in the BIOS settings to reset it.

If that fails for any reason, you'll probably need to take it in to a repair shop.

Comment: Thanks Julie. BIOS settings were not changed at all throughout the process. Yet, if it's not going to stop my system from booting, I'll try resetting it.

Comment: Isn't your system already unusable?  The idea is to try an external keyboard and if that works, you'll at least be able to further troubleshoot as you are now unable to do anything.

Comment: As I've mentioned in my second last para, I already tried connecting external keyboard. However, I'll give resetting BIOS a shot and see if it does any magic for me.

Comment: Then your only option, if you are comfortable doing it, is to reset the BIOS through the motherboard jumper or CMOS battery short.

Comment: I persist in thinking there is a hardware issue, most likely with the motherboard or its connections.

Comment: Yes, I reckon the same. I'm gonna try BIOS reset or else I'm taking it to service center. After googling it a bit, I found that not able to login is related to some catalyst driver. Let's see. Thanks very much for the help. Appreciate it :)